# Date-time format in the JIRA REST API giving error response Operation value must be a string

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am passing the below JOSN with the POST request to create the Jira issue. One of the parameters is the starting date and time (customfield_10603
).On the JIRA app we have date and time picker for this field.
In what format this value should be sent out. I tried with 2018-06-17T00:00:00.0+0000. 
JSON sent:

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   { 
      "key": "HOA"
   },
   "summary": "Test ticket for JIRA_Jenkins integration.",
          "customfield_10616":{"value":"Other"},

   "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
   "customfield_10603": {"value":"2018-06-17T00:00:00.0+0000"},
   "issuetype": {"name": "Change Request" },
   "customfield_10624": {"value":"Low"},
   "customfield_12100": {"value" :"Low"},
   "customfield_10625": {"value":"SRE"},
   "customfield_10615": {"value":"Routine"}
 }
    }
```

received response:

```
{
"errorMessages": [],
"errors": {
    "customfield_10603": "Operation value must be a string"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

"customfield_10603": "2018-06-17T00:00:00.0+0000".